# How to show part of RawImage only in the Panel?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I created a Canvas UI and put a Panel in it, then put a RawImage in the Panel.

```
Canvas
╰Panel
 ╰RawImage
```

The full image of the RawImage will be shown no matter the size, even if it's bigger than the Panel.

How can I show only the part which the Panel envelope!?

I tried `Content Size Fitter` but seems like it got nothing to do with it!

I'm sorry that I didn't try other things other than move things around.

Because I **REALLY** don't even know where to start!?

Could somebody PLEASE be so kind and teach me how to attach such a thing.

Much appreciated!

[Screenshots](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I456Q.jpg)

Comment: add some images of your problem.

Comment: you could use a mask?

Comment: Actually I misread at first, ignore my previous comment if you already read it. What @BugFinder said is what you're looking for. [UI mask](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.ugui@1.0/manual/script-Mask.html)

Comment: Thanks! It worked! Could you please be so kind and post it as an answer so I could check for the best answer!? Much appreciated!